# what happens when tried to free memory allocated by heap manager, which allocates more than asked for?

Tags: c++, c, malloc, heap-memory, free

This question was asked to me in an interview.

Suppose char *p=malloc(n) assigns more than n,say N bytes of memory are allocated and free(p) is used to free the memory allocated to p.

can heap manager perform such faulty allocation ?
what happens now, will n bytes are freed or N bytes are freed?

is there any method to find how much memory is freed?

**EDIT**

*is there any method to find how much memory is freed?*

better than nothing,

mallinfo() can shed some light as pointed by "Fred Larson"

Comment: Why do you think such an allocation is faulty?  Regardless of how many "actual" bytes `malloc()` allocated, you can use only `n` bytes, and `free()` will free all of the allocated bytes.  Most `malloc` implementations allocate more space then requested for efficiency reasons.  An implementation defines `malloc` and `free`, and by definition, they have to agree on a scheme of allocation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, that's what happens almost every time do you a `malloc()`.  The `malloc` block header contains information about the the size of the block, and when `free()` is called, it returns that amount back to the heap.  It's not faulty, it's expected operation.

A simple implementation might, for instance, store just the size of the block in the space immediately preceding the returned pointer.  Then, `free()` would look something like this:

```
void free(void *ptr)
{
    size_t *size = (size_t *)ptr - 1;

    return_to_heap(ptr, *size);
}
```

Where `return_to_heap()` is used here to mean a function that does the actual work of returning the specified block of memory to the heap for future use.

Comment: Is there a method to find out how much memory is freed?

Comment: @rozuur: All memory allocated by `malloc()` will be freed by `free()`.  I think your real question is how to find out how much memory was allocated.  (And the answer?  At least as much as was requested, if the allocation was successful.)

Comment: rozuur: look at this page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms220938(VS.80).aspx

it gives an idea about what is actually done when you ask for a chunk of memory. Most implementations are very similar to this.

Comment: @rozuur The important point is it doesn't *matter* how big the allocation really is.  These are implementation details and you shouldn't worry about them too much, unless you suspect they are causing you problems, which most of the time they will not.

Comment: @Rozur, and for posterity!  1) All memory allocate will be released (`N`, as per the question).  2) Whether or not you can find out exactly how much memory is allocated depends on whether the memory manager publishes this information.  3) There is no standard function to obtain the number of bytes allocated by `malloc()` (although different vendors may choose to provide such a function).  4) Many memory managers round up `n` to the next power of two, thus ensuring you never waste more than half your memory.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the heap manager is allowed to return a block of more than *n* bytes.  It is completely safe (and required!) to free the returned pointer using `free`, and `free` will deallocate all of it.

Many heap implementations track their allocations by inserting blocks of metadata into the heap.  `free` will look for that metadata to determine how much memory to deallocate.  This is implementation-specific, though, so there's no way to know how much `malloc` gave you, and generally, you shouldn't care.

Answer (score 1):

Generally the heap manager will free whatever it allocated.  It stores this info somewhere, and looks it up when `free()` is called.

A heap manager is not "faulty" if it allocates more memory than was requested. Heap managers often work with fixed block sizes, and will round up to the next appropriate block size when satisfying a request. The heap manager's job is to be as efficient as possible, and often big efficiencies result from a few small inefficiencies.

Comment: "often big efficiencies result from a few small inefficiencies" Nice quote 8^)

Answer (score 1):

This is the default behavior of malloc.  It will return `NULL` or a pointer to a section of memory at least as long as the one you asked for.  So yes free must be able to handle getting rid of memory longer than what was asked for.

Finding out how much memory was actually free or allocated is a platform specific question.

Answer (score 1):

Other answers have explained well how the block size is handled.  To find out how much memory is freed, the only solution I can think of is to call `mallinfo()` before and after the free.